# Show raw data from table in PowerBI

Tags: excel, database, powerbi, data-visualization, visualization

is it possible to view raw data data build table? For example [example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4hbBX.png) if I clicked one of this number is it possible to see all raw rows that was summarize in columns customer, finance, etc. I am looking for some view that is using in pivot tables in excel/google sheets. There are option that  if you clicked in one cell there will be created new tab with filtered source data.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the drillthrough feature to accomplish this.  Basically, create a second page and create a table with all the data you want to see.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/create-reports/desktop-drillthrough

Comment: Yeah this is one of the option. But if someone wants more specific info about single rows  there are need to create manually another page with another data?

Comment: You asked is for way build table data.  This is how to do that. If you need a different behavior,  please expand. Power bi can't intuitively show data.